# "UnsatisfiedLinkError" on Android JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

In my project, I have a wrapper class named `PlayerCluster.java`, which loads the native lib, and provides native functions. If I changed the class name (`PlayerCluster.java`) or its package, I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` when native function is invoked.

Why do I get this error when I rename the class name? Is there an approach by which native lib must be loaded in a specific java class?

Comment: Your question was good but I included the whole error because it gives more information and makes it easier to find. People will answer faster is your question contains a lot of information. _ _ _ _ I also strongly suggest that you accept an answer that was provided if it answers to your question. By doing that, you will also receive points so it will be rewarding for both of you. Moreover, if you accept an answer that is valid for you, your question will not show up in the Unanswered section. So people like me will not waste time on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename the class then you must also rename your `JNIEXPORT` methods in your native library so they match the new Java class name and then **rebuild** your native lib.

For example, given this method signture:

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_com_mn_rootscape_utils_NativeMethods_getFilesPermissions( JNIEnv* env, jobject thizz, jobjectArray filePathsArray )
```

`NativeMethods` is the Java class which, as you can see, is part of the native function signature.

Comment: OK. Consider accepting the answer after you make sure it's what you needed.